# Angular and Tomcat url

Tags: angular, tomcat

[image]I have published an angular app under the Tomcat and it works fine  but  as soon as the user refresh the page Tomcat answers that he can't find the URL (previous handled with the angular-routing), to the other hand instead using localhost 'ng serve' it works fine.

any idea how to solve it ?

thanks

Comment: maybe you need to add   `{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },` to provider in app.module

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: do you have a server side framework like spring (+mvc) bundled in the war as well?

Comment: thank you but Apache and Apache Tomcat are differents for example I don't have .htacess hidden file tp put the regular expression

Comment: @itsallas no it's just an apache tomcat folder

Answer (score 0):

The application deep links will not work without the redirect rule on the server. All the deep links have to redirect to the application `index.html` by the server.

To setup the tomcat to redirect any deep links -

1. Configure the RewriteValve in server.xml
2. Write the rewrite rule in rewrite.config

**1. Configure the RewriteValve in server.xml**

Edit the ~/conf/server.xml to add the below Valve inside the Host section as below –

```
...
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />

...
      </Host>
...
```

**2. Write the rewrite rule in rewrite.config**

Create directory structure – ~/conf/Catalina/localhost/ and create the rewrite.config file inside it with the below content. Note - here I am considering `/hello` as the context path of the application.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/hello/(.*) /hello/index.html
```

After setting this up restart the tomcat server and you can hit the deep links of the application which will route to the correct components inside the angular application.

You can refer to [this post](http://codedumpster.nithinbiliya.com/deep-linking-issue-angular-application-tomcat-server/) for more details.